# Cannot read property 'nTh' of undefined datatable using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, codeigniter-3

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        var dataTable = $('#example5').DataTable({
              scrollX:true,
              "sScrollY": "1200px",
              "sScrollCollapse": true,
              "paging": true,
              dom: 'lBfrtip',
              scrollX:true,
              scrollCollapse: true,
              lengthMenu: [[10,25,50,100, -1], [10,25,50,100, "All"]],
              buttons: [{ 
                          extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'Download Excel',
                          exportOptions: {
                                columns: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42]
                          }
              }],
              fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: 3,
                    rightColumns:1
              },
              search: false, 
              language: {
                    processing: "<img src='"+base_url+"uploads/images/loading-circle.gif'>",
                    paginate: {
                          next: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                          previous: '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>'  
                    }
              },
              "processing":true,  
              "serverSide":true,  
              "order":[], 
              "bStateSave": true, 
              "ajax":{  
                    url:base_url+'student/ajaxAcademicStudents',  
                    type:"POST"
              }, 
              "columnDefs": [
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":0},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":1},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":2},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":3},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":4},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":5},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":6},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":7},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":8},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":9},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":10},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":11},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":12},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":13},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":14},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":15},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":16},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":17},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":18},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":19},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":20},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":21},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":22},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":23},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":24},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":25},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":26},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":27},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":28},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":29},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":30},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":31},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":32},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":33},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":34},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":35},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":36},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":37},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":38},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":39},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":40},
                    { "orderable": false,"targets":41},
              ], 
              "columns": [
                    { "data": "check" },
                    { "data": "sn2" },
                    { "data": "counsellor" },
                    { "data": "urnno" },
                    { "data": "application" },
                    { "data": "session" },
                    { "data": "examSession" },              
                    { "data": "classes" },
                    { "data": "sub_course" },
                    { "data": "year" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "father_name" },
                    { "data": "mother_name" },
                    { "data": "sex" },
                    { "data": "dob" },
                    { "data": "employment_status" },
                    { "data": "castcategory" },
                    { "data": "nationality" },
                    { "data": "phone" },
                    { "data": "email" },
                    { "data": "state" },
                    { "data": "city" },
                    { "data": "address" },
                    { "data": "applicant_area" },
                    { "data": "pin" },
                    { "data": "10th_board_name" },
                    { "data": "10th_year_passing" },
                    { "data": "10th_percentage" },
                    { "data": "10th_division" },
                    { "data": "10th_main_subject" },
                    { "data": "12th_board_name" },
                    { "data": "12th_year_passing" },
                    { "data": "12th_percentage" },
                    { "data": "12th_division" },
                    { "data": "12th_main_subject" },
                    { "data": "graduation" },
                    { "data": "graduation_year_passing" },
                    { "data": "graduation_percentage" },
                    { "data": "graduation_division" },
                    { "data": "graduation_main_subject" },
                    { "data": "aadhar" },
                    { "data": "application_no" },
              ], 
        }); 
        dataTable.on('draw.dt', function () {
              var info = dataTable.page.info();
              dataTable.column(1, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied', page: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
                    cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + info.start;
              });
        }); 
  });
```

I am using datatable to show large amount of data in my table. All data are showing perfectly in my table but whwen I tried to export table into `excel` sheet then nothing can happen and this message are showing in my console I am not aware about this `Cannot read property 'nTh' of undefined`. So, How can I fix this issue and export table data into excel? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 6):

Its because the number of column/index you have specified in exportOptions->columns does not match with the number table column.

Suppose You have four column: Sl, Name, Email, Phone. The exportOptions->columns should be:

```
exportOptions: {
    columns: [0,1,2,3]
}
```

Comment: Yes!! this is the solutions! Thanks dear you saved my times!